# Removing Duplicate Frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a 4.7-second mp4 file with several duplicate frames inserted every second or so. I would like to remove these frames. I ran ffmpeg on  it with:

```
ffmpeg -i samp1.mp4 -vf mpdecimate -vsync vfr out3.mp4
```

and this did indeed remove the duplicates. The file went from 142 frames and 88 duplicates to 54 frames and no duplicates.  But the length of the output file is still about 4.7 seconds so it displays at about 54/4.7 = 9fps, which is jerky.  The reason for removing the duplicate frames was to get rid of the jerkiness they caused, but at 9fps, now, I've still got the jerkiness. I'd like the output to display at 24fps after the duplicates  are removed, so the clip would play smoothly for about 2 seconds and end.  Could someone suggest the right way to do this?

Thank you!  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to retime the frames using the `setpts` filter.

```
ffmpeg -i samp1.mp4 -vf mpdecimate,setpts=N/24/TB -vsync vfr out3.mp4
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you!  BTW, what forum do you usually answer FFMpeg questions on?  Someone here keeps complaining that FFMpeg questions are off topic here. Thanks.